# Convert anorm result to an Iterator

Tags: scala, anorm

Is there a way to convert an anorm result to an Iterator (hacky solutions are fine)?
I'm fine with getting an `Iterator[Row]` or `Iterator[MyTypeAfterDeser]`.

If not is there a hook to get from anorm the plain jdbc `ResultSet` and then go from `ResultSet` to `Row` so I can reuse existing parsing code and `RowParser`?

I'm looking to then implement automatic joins over these iterators on the client side.

PS: I'm already aware of Akka Streams, but this is not what I want.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://playframework.github.io/anorm/#streaming-results

Comment: @cchantep the cursor API allows you to read in a streaming fashion but not to produce a streamable structure (like an iterator). So the result of foldWhile or withResult is a datastructure that has loaded already whatever it needed from the resultset. This is different from returning an iterator that keeps the db connection open and allows you to load one item at a time.

Comment: Nope, cursor is lazy

Comment: @cchantep withResult is closing the result set, so the function that you pass to it needs to consume the cursor and returned a fully loaded in memory data structure. Perhaps you could try giving a more developed answer using some code as example?